# Loading data from AWS redshift using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I'm facing a mission impossible to extract a huge amount of data from Amazone Redshift to another table. It definitely requires a more efficient approach but I'm new to SQL and AWS so decided to ask this smart community for advice.

This is my initial SQL query which takes forever:

```
-- STEP 1: CREATE A SAMPLE FOR ONE MONTH
SELECT DISTINCT at_id, utc_time, name
INTO my_new_table
FROM s3_db.table_x
WHERE type = 'create' 
AND (dt BETWEEN '20181001' AND '20181031');
```

What would be the best approach? I was thinking of using python and sqlalchemy to create dataframes with chunks of 1m rows and inserting it back into the new table (which I need to create beforehand). Would this work?:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
import pandas as pd

redshift_user = os.environ['REDSHIFT_USER']
redshift_password = os.environ['REDSHIFT_PASSWORD']

engine_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" \
% (redshift_user, redshift_password, 'localhost', XXXX, 'redshiftdb')
engine = create_engine(engine_string)

for df in pd.read_sql_query("""
                        SELECT DISTINCT at_id, utc_time, name
                        INSERT INTO my_new_table
                        FROM s3_db.table_x
                        WHERE type = 'create' 
                        AND (dt BETWEEN '20181001' AND '20181031');
                       """, engine, chunksize=1000000):
```

Comment: you’re moving data from one redshift table to another redshift table?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: database operation will ultimately be faster than going to pandas and then back to redshift, the problem is it takes to long right now?

Comment: Exactly - nearly impossible to complete as I get broken pipe time to time a loose everything. Is there a way doing it in chunks in SQL?

Comment: You need to take a more detailed look at how the source table is structured. Is it an actual Redshift table, or as the name "s3_db" seems to imply, is it a Spectrum table? If the latter, the data may exist as files in S3 rather than Redshift itself and you can potentially use other tools such as EMR/Spark, Athena or Glue to create the new data set. If it IS an actual Redshift table then check what the distribution key and sort key are for the source table. If you can apply a filter to the sort key this may help speed up the query.

Comment: please can you clarify - are you trying to copy from s3? (ie - is s3_db a spectrum schema?) if so - you should try replacing your approach with a redshift copy command first to copy into redshift followed by your transform logic (select distinct) as a CTAS as john describes in his answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right - s3_db is a Spectrum table.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [CREATE TABLE AS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html).

This allows you to specify a `SELECT` statement and have the results directly stored into a new table.

This is *hugely* more efficient than downloading data and re-uploading.

You can also `CREATE TABLE LIKE` and then load it with data. See: [Performing a Deep Copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/performing-a-deep-copy.html)

You could also `UNLOAD` data to Amazon S3, then load it again via `COPY`, but using `CREATE TABLE AS` is definitely the best option.

Comment: John, this is good general logic but in this case i the the OP is trying to copy from s3 to redshift (we need clarification)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer AWS guidelines for RedShift and Spectrum best practices; I've put the links at the end of this post. Based on your question, I am assuming you want to extract, transform and load huge amount of data from RedShift Spectrum based table "s3_db.table_x" to new RedShift table "my_new_table"

Here are some suggestions based on AWS recommendations:

1. Create your RedShift table with appropriate distribution key, sort key and compression encoding. At high level, "at_id" seems best suited as partition key and "utc_time" as sortkey for your requirement, but make sure to refer AWS guidelines for RedShift table design [3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-preamble-prerequisites-and-prioritization/).
2. As you mentioned, your data volume is huge, you may like to have your S3 source table "s3_db.table_x" partitioned based on "type" and "dt" columns (as suggested at point number 4 in spectrum best practices [1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/)).
3. Replace `DISTINCT`with `GROUP BY` in the select query from Spectrum (point number 9 in Spectrum Best Practices [1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/)).
4. AWS recommends (point number 7 in Spectrum best practices [1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/)) to simplify your ETL process using `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` or `SELECT INTO` statements, wherein you may put your transformation logic in the select component to load data directly form S3 to RedShift.

[redshift spectrum best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/)

[redshift best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-techniques-for-amazon-redshift/)

[redshift table design playbook](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-preamble-prerequisites-and-prioritization/)

Answer (score 0):

It now appears that your source data is stored in Amazon S3 and you have been using a Redshift Spectrum table (that points to data in S3) as your source.

The preferred method would be:

- Use the Amazon Redshift `COPY` command to load the data into a Redshift table
- Use a `CREATE TABLE AS` command to extract (ETL) the data from the new Redshift table into your desired table. If you do this on a regular basis, you can use `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT INTO` to reload the table in future.